# Crash using strcpy into an offset of a data structure

Tags: c

I have a particular data structure used in a C program which I am using to attach type information to values.  A simple example looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct teststruct
{
    char type;
    union {
        char s;
        int i;
        float f;
    } value;
};

int main()
{
    struct teststruct *t = malloc(sizeof(struct teststruct)+10);
    t->type = 'i';
    t->value.i = 42;
    free(t);

    t = malloc(sizeof(struct teststruct)+10);
    t->type = 's';
    strcpy(&t->value.s, "test");

    free(t);

    printf("Finished without errors.\n");
}
```

As you can see, my intention is to use the `type` field to identify the value's type, and use the `value` field to contain a union of the possible values.  When the data is a string, the idea is to allocate more memory than `sizeof(struct teststruct)` and then access the string with `&t->value.s`.

Although this works, it is apparently problematic for the optimiser.  Using `gcc` version 4.7.2, I get the following in non-optimised conditions:

```
$ gcc -O0 -o test test.c
$ ./test 
Finished without errors.
```

No problem.  However, under the optimiser, it gives me a warning:

```
$ gcc -O2 -o test test.c
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:642:0,
                 from test.c:4:
In function ‘strcpy’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at test.c:25:15:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:105:3: warning: call to __builtin___memcpy_chk will always overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]
```

And indeed,

```
$ ./test 
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./test terminated
```

However, if I replace `strcpy` with `memcpy`, this works fine, and it also works well if I replace `strcpy` with a `for`-loop.  However, `strncpy` crashes just like `strcpy`.  I am absolutely not overwritten outside of `malloc`'ed memory, so I don't know why this is crashing.

I realize that copying into a weird offset of the data structure is not so usual, so the question is, am I violating some semantic contract of `strcpy`, or is this a bug in the compiler?

Thanks.

Comment: It is wrong to just allocate more space and copy your string there, but it doesn't crash on mine.
$ gcc -O2 -o test test.c
$ ./test
Finished without errors.

Comment: Why is it wrong? I am curious about it not crashing for you, as this is repeatable for me on several machines. However, i have only tested it on 32-bit machines, are you using a 64-bit architecture by any chance?

Comment: Okay I tested on MingW just now, it does not crash.  So this crash only occurs on Linux.  Very strange.  It seems to have something to do with the inlining of `strcpy`.

Comment: I get a warning about this with g++ 4.8 on Fedora, but it's accepted by g++4.9 on Ubuntu. It's concerning that it might crash. But using memcpy instead is acceptable for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not valid here:

```
strcpy(&t->value.s, "test");
// value.s is a single char, not a string that you can store
// an arbitrary number of characters into.
//
```

You either need to give `s` some space

```
struct teststruct
{
    char type;
    union {
        char s[10]; // length depends on your specific needs
        int i;
        float f;
    } value;
};
```

OR
make s a pointer and dynamically allocate as required

```
struct teststruct
{
    char type;
    union {
        char *s;
        int i;
        float f;
    } value;
};
// instead of strcpy(&t->value.s, "test"); use t->value.s = strdup("test")
// don't forget to free the space when you are done.
```

Comment: Did you notice the size passed to `malloc` in myexample code? There should be plenty of space for the string.

Comment: Those solutions work when the struct is being used only within the program it's allocated in. If you're passing the memory between threads/programs the char * introduces significant issues. Often it's considerably simpler to simply use the memory you have as the OP does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no gcc expert myself, but after reading [1], I believe gcc -O2 is implementing that strcpy() call with a memcpy, and using __builtin___memcpy_chk to check for overflows.

According to the example in [1] the reasons for __builtin___memcpy_chk is apparently to check the destination object length, and allow to catch buffer overflows at runtime.

And also as per [1], you'll get a compile-time warning if gcc knows at compile time that __builtin___memcpy_chk *itself* will overflow.

If you still wish to retain your obscure char array allocation, I'd say you should at least use a safe strcpy:

```
strncpy(&t->value.s, "test", 9);
```

Notice that I can't trigger this behavior on my machine, and thus I can't disassemble the code to take a look at what's really going on.

[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html

Comment: Found a way to reproduce the reported behavior: `gcc  a.c -O2 -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`. And also, my strncpy suggestion didn't help :-)